# Where are the Ruby Class Singleton Constants Stored?

Tags: ruby, singleton, constants

Let's assume we have this Ruby class:

```
class MyClass
  class << self
    MC_CONST = 30
  end
end
```

Then, let's instantiate `MyClass` and add another constant to the object's metaclass:

```
m = MyClass.new
class << m
  OBJ_MC_CONST = 50
end
```

There are no issues with the object singleton constant:

```
m.singleton_class::OBJ_MC_CONST # => 50 <-- [OK]
m.singleton_class.constants.include? :OBJ_MC_CONST # => true <- [OK]
```

But not exactly what I'd expect with the class singleton constant:

```
MyClass.singleton_class::MC_CONST # => 30 <-- [OK]
MyClass.singleton_class.const_get :MC_CONST # => 30 <-- [OK]
MyClass.singleton_class.constants.include? :MC_CONST # => false <-- [Why???]
```

Why on earth the array returned by `.constants` method on metaclass of `MyClass` class doesn't contain :MC_CONST? What am I missing here?

Thank you.

---

**EDIT 1:** This does appear to be a bug in MRI 2.x after all. I've filed a new issue with the Ruby core team: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9413 to address this.

**EDIT 2:** This bug has apparently been fixed in https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/44628/diff/

Answer (score 5):

I've explored a bit on this question and I think it is caused by a bug / inconsistency / idiosyncrasy of MRI.

On MRI 2.1.0, this code:

```
class MyClass
  class << self
    MC_CONST = 30
  end
end 

p MyClass.singleton_class.const_defined? :ABBA_CONST, false
p MyClass.singleton_class.const_defined? :MC_CONST, false
p MyClass.singleton_class.constants(false)
```

yields

```
false
true
[]
```

So the `MC_CONST` constant is defined, but it is not available as a local constant of the class (I'm passing false to the various methods to disable the constant resolution and just keep it local to that class), which it should be indeed. If we check on the documentation of [Module#constants](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-constants) it says:

> Returns an array of the names of the constants accessible in mod. This
>   includes the names of constants in any included modules (example at
>   start of section), unless the all parameter is set to false.
>
> Also see **Module::const_defined?**.

So it tells us to check `const_defined?` to better understand the behaviour of `constants`, but the two methods give different results!

---

Furthermore, on other Ruby implementation this code works as expected.

On JRuby 1.7.9, it yields:

```
false
true
[:MC_CONST]
```

On Rubinius 2.2.1, it yields:

```
false
true
[:MC_CONST]
```

Which is the expected behaviour :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I does appear to be a bug in current MRI. I've filed a new issue with the Ruby core team. I will update the description with the issue URL.